# Xcode 4 and xcode 5 together

Tags: xcode4, ios7, xcode5

Can i install Xcode 5 and Ios 7 Beta together with the xcode 4 ?

I have xcode 4, can I install also xcode 5 with Ios 7, Is the any problem for my project developed with xcode 4 on ios 6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, both can be installed and you can have both running simultaneously.  It would probably be a bad idea to try using them both on the same project at the same time though.

Keep in mind that Xcode generally doesn't like to open xib or storyboard files that were last modified by a later release of Xcode.

Comment: I setup xcode 5, and change default xcode version but still when I double click my old project, xcode 5 is opening. Why? how can change it?